# Open multi lined text file and read only an specific line in it. and send the value to a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, save

I have created a code that generates a multi-lined text file.

What I would like to achieve is read only a specific line and send that value to a specific textbox.

Below is my form :

[image: My form with textboxes]

My Text file sample and What I want to achieve please see below :

[image: What I want to achieve]

Please see below my code :

```
            var open = new OpenFileDialog();

        open.Title = "Open File";

        open.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            FilePathLB.Text = open.InitialDirectory + open.FileName;

            StreamReader read = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(open.FileName));

            //X1TB.Text = File.ReadLines(open.FileName).Skip(1).Take(1).First();
            //X1TB.Text = read.ReadLine();
            X1TB.Text = read.ReadLine();




            read.Dispose();
        }
```

thanks for all those who will help.

Comment: It's practically a requirement that you at least make some effort yourself before asking for help. Have you written any code at all?

Comment: so, if you know how to generate a file, what problems specifically are you having of reading it in? what have you tried, where is your code?

Comment: sorry i forgot to post it cause i just left my sit. Anyways I have form that contains dozens of text boxes. So The code i'm using is it can read the text file but it cannot set the values for each line in text to send in every text boxes.

Comment: What is wrong with using `ReadLine()`? Each time you call it, it advances to the next line, until it returns null (which means you've reached the end of the file).

Comment: @john Sample the first line goes to textbox1.text then etc. I tried to code but i couldn't figured. (noob here)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read each line sequentially:

```
using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(open.FileName)))
{
    X1TB.Text = read.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;
    X2TB.Text = read.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;
    X3TB.Text = read.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;
}
```

I've added `?? string.Empty` so that if `read.ReadLine()` returns null, we'll set the textbox value to an empty string. `read.ReadLine()` returns null when the end of the file has been reached.

Alternatively you could put all of your textboxes in an array:

```
var textboxes = new [] { X1TB, X2TB, X3TB };
using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(open.FileName)))
{
    foreach (var textbox in textboxes)
    {
        textbox.Text = read.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: i will try your code john. I have forgotten this array, I've never used it before. I'll let you know if your code works.

Comment: Your code worked. But the values are not centered in the textbox. Why's that? I did look in my textboxes all are aligned to center. I tried this but still the values are not centered "X1TB.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;"